# Wordpress theme code in simple PHP website

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a php website, in which I have used a lot of jquery plugins and accessing another database for header and footer contents dynamically.Now I have to add a blog for which I am checking wordpress. I can create the theme, but cannot access the header and footer dynamic contents from other DB. Is there some other to access the wordpress theme loop and other theme functions in my simple php pages? If no then any suggestion about other simple php blog script to add in the website with SEO support please.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include files as you wish in a Wordpress template using include() or require(). Just put your PHP files with your template files and you should be good to go.

Here's how you can forego Wordpress entirely and display something from your old website, if your old website now lives inside of your template folder:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'show_old_page');
function show_old_page() {
    if( $_GET['old_page'] == 'pagename' ) {
        include( TEMPLATE_PATH . 'oldpage.php' );
        exit;
    }
}
```